# MySQL ODBC Stored Procedure result is missing columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures, odbc

I have a set of stored procedures that I am using to populate an ASP.Net CheckBoxList. When running this procedure from code as { CALL ProcedureName(params); } with the type set as stored procedure, I only seem to be getting a partial result back (i.e. many columns from the actual result are missing.)

If I copy the CommandText from the query (having used a breakpoint to get the exact text sent) and run it directly in Navicat (or any other MySQL GUI), I get all of the expected columns.

Here is the code that is not working:

```
using (OdbcCommand command = OdbcConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "{ " + string.Format(StoredProcedureCall, foundationId, fpids, "", "", "NULL", "2001/01/02", "2001/01/01", "*") +
                          " }";
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the code to the following however it starts to work (only adding the other using):

```
using (OdbcConnection)
using (OdbcCommand command = OdbcConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "{ " + string.Format(StoredProcedureCall, foundationId, fpids, "", "", "NULL", "2001/01/02", "2001/01/01", "*") +
                          " }";
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on here?

For reference here is the OdbcConnection property:

```
public static OdbcConnection OdbcConnection
{
    get
    {
        // If we have no connection or our connection isn't open
        if (null == odbcConnection || ConnectionState.Open != odbcConnection.State)
        {
            odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(BaseAccess.DBConnectionString);
            odbcConnection.Open();
        }

        return odbcConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your application using the same login credentials as Navicat?

Comment: Yes, they are running with the same user/password

Comment: how did you find out that columns are missing? what are you using to store the data sent by the SP?

Comment: The result in the ODBC reader in the C# code is read into a list. This list is where many columns are missing (and what is used as the datasource for the CheckBoxList)

Comment: this can be a bug in ODBC/MySql. Do the missing columns have the same type? or something else in common? can you use ADO.NET Driver for MySQL instead of ODBC and see the results?

Comment: We have just switched to the ADO.Net driver and now with OR without the extra using statement there are missing columns. Anyone have a clue what in the MySQL side could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was somehow related to connections being reused and some of the @ variables in stored procedures not being reset between runs. Changing to pooled connections that are closed/disposed of correctly is what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a bug in the Odbc MySql driver. Try using the [ADO.NET driver](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). Also I would advice you against handling the connections manually inside static properties. Leave this task to ADO.NET which will effectively handle a connection pool:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_name";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@foundationId", foundationId));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fpids", fpids));
    ...

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ADO.Net driver actually makes the problem worse. It doesn't return all the columns with OR without the extra using statement.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your columns all have unique names.

Comment: Non uniquely named columns would throw a MySQL Exception. There is no such exception. Not to mention that the procedure forces unique column names as part of the code because they are all numbered (q1: blah, q2: blah, etc.)